# Change font size for iPad Pro in steps

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

I have an app, which is intended only for iPad in landscape mode. The screen design is completely done in IB with autolayout.

Now I want to achieve the following behaviour: All the labels should have font size 48 when on iPad Pro 12", and for all smaller iPad sizes the font size should be 32.

I tried various options in IB with autoshrink and minimum font size, but then the app picks font sizes in between 48 - 32 and gives a random look. But I only want to have 48 for 12" or 32 for all smaller devices - nothing in between in order to get a consistent look.

My next idea was to set a fixed font size in IB for all labels to 32, and give all labels a tag and in each viewcontroller on ´viewDidLoad´ run the following code:

**Extension for UIDevice**

```
public var isPadPro12: Bool {
    if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad
        && UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.height == 2732) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

**Code called in ´viewDidLoad´**

```
func adjustFont() {
    let isPro12 = UIDevice.current.isPadPro12
    if isPro12 {
        for subview in view.subviews {
            if subview.tag == 999 {
                if let labelView = subview as? UILabel {
                    labelView.font = labelView.font.withSize(48)
                    print ("font size \(labelView.font)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works only for some labels, some others are still in 32. What can I do to force the label to 48? Is there a problem with autolayout? The label has only a width constraint and a top margin, and X/Y position.

**EDIT**
When I add the debug print after the font size adjustment, I get the following result:

```
font size Optional(<UICTFont: 0x7fcbf7c2ea90> font-family: "Arial"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 48.00pt)
```

But the font size is definitely not 48. It looks different than setting the font size in IB directly to 48.

Comment: Are you sure that you set up 999 as the tag for all your labels?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: You are not doing a deep loop here. Are you sure all your labels are in view level ?

Comment: @Gihan: yes, all labels are direct children of the view. I did print debugs in the loop above, and the line with the font size adjustment is definitely called.

Comment: You should not base these decisions on device type. Do you still want the different font when the user is using multitasking and your app is only using up 1/3 of the screen? Base decisions on view size, not device.

Comment: @rmaddy: Multitasking is disabled. The different font sizes for the devices are an explizit requirement of the client. It's non discussable... :(

Comment: It's possible that the text in that size will not fit and the reduce font size to fit option is selected for those labels. That said, this is a poor approach to control layout.

Comment: @picciano: I think it is enough space around, but is there any debug option?

Comment: If the labels fonts are not changing size then either the setting of the font is either not being done on the label, the label is adjusting font size based on the text (check the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property) or something else is adjusting the font afterwards.  Autolayout itself won't be adjusting the font sizing it's just concerned with the layout of the controls.  However as others have said the approach is wrong no matter what your client may say (this should have been pointed out before taking on the job).  What happens with an iPad mini for example which is much smaller.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth: What would be your approach then to adjust all labels consistently so that all the labels will have always the same font size on the current device, but still scale up and down on the various iPad sizes?

Comment: I would not base anything on an actual device size at all.  You are also going to run into problems with dynamic font sizing if you want to support that (which you should if possible).

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth: How would you make sure then that the layout is consistent over the iPad devices?

Comment: Make use of the tools given so use the ability to adjust font size based on the space available rather than hardcoded sizes.  Also consider more than just the font size.  An iPad Pro screen size is sufficiently larger than an iPad Mini that the entire interface itself could be different. Unfortunately I have to go out or I would discuss it further.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth: This again ignores the requirement that all labels need to have the same font size on the screen. Given tools like autolayout and size classes doesn't support this. With given tools you always get a mess of different and inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: True but we had strayed from the original requirements slightly.  So back to the original requirement then and it's not auto-layout that is causing issues.  It must be either the labels are not having their font set, they are set to adjust their fonts or some other part of your code resets the font of the labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Subclass UILabel, set that class for every uilabel in your Interface Builder.
2. Create a enum for all different types/fonts you want to support, and create a function in that enum that returns e.g. a font size
3. Determine the current device and store it in a value from the enum
4. Override the initializers for your subclassed UILabel in step 1 and get the font size from the variabele defined in step 3, with the vales in step 2

Code:

```
var currentScreen = Screens.iPadLarge //change this to current device


enum Screens{
    case iPadLarge, iPadSmall
    func getFont() -> CGFloat{
        switch self{
        case .iPadLarge:
            return 40
        case .iPadSmall:
            return 20
        }
    }
}

class MyLabel: UILabel{

    init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonLoad()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonLoad()
    }

    func commonLoad(){
        let fontSize = currentScreen.getFont()
        //use fontSize
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have code examples, particularly for step 4? thanks.

Comment: @FrankZp, are you expecting to see this in IB? Otherwise, this sounds pretty straight-forward. (And yes, you *cannot* see it in IB.)

Comment: @FrankZp yes in 10 minutes i can write some example code, i think it is not possible to dispay the results instant in interfacebuilder because the output is not generated at compile time

Comment: @J.Doe: ok thanks. I am aware of not seeing this in IB. I just asked for adding code to your reply.

Comment: @J.Doe: Thanks for the code. Unfortunately, the same thing happens - when adding ´self.font = font.withSize(fontSize)´ to your code, the label won't display in a bigger font size, but if I do a print debug on the label it shows me that the font size is set bigger - but it isn't. Clueless...

Comment: @FrankZp weird, it works for me, maybe if you make a clean project with only my code in it and 1 label, it really should work

Comment: This is a good implementation that should work perfectly fine.  Can you check with that the labels that aren't changing are actually being set and then nothing is resetting them.  If you are now subclassing UILabel you could override the setting of the font and add a didSet to allow debugging.  You might also be able to get it working in Interface Builder if you were to set it as an IBDesignable.

Comment: How can we do this in ObjectiveC?