# Make responsive label font size for iphone devices

Tags: ios, font-size, ios-autolayout

I am new to iOS Development.I am having problem with font size with phone screen size.For example Font size in iPhone 8 Plus looks fine but that text size is bigger in iPhone SE.I tried check Dynamic Type to Automatically Adjusts Font.And try to play with Autoshrink in StoryBoard.And i also tried to Add Font Variation in storyBoard.But I didnt get any good solution.Hope you understand my problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change font size for iPad Pro in steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811797/change-font-size-for-ipad-pro-in-steps)

Comment: Check out that question and my answer, should help you

Comment: use this  "yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true"

Comment: okay you can change by using constraint.

Comment: How to change fontsize using constraints? MRizwan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class func dynamicFontSizeForIphone(fontSize : CGFloat) -> CGFloat
{
    var current_Size : CGFloat = 0.0
    current_Size = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width/320) //320*568 is my base
    let FinalSize : CGFloat = fontSize * current_Size
    return FinalSize

}
```

hope this work

Answer (score 1):

You can change font size by using constraints.

1.take a label give its basic two constraint to satisfy. give one more constraint of equal.width to parent view. keep width as wide as your label text is.(a bit more than label text).

2. In attribute inspector there is a property name 'auto shrink' set it to 'minimum font size'

thats it.

Note: This will work fine if your Label text is constant. For changeable text there will be other approaches.