# What is the most efficient way (best practice) to style text (e.g. UILabel, Button titles) in XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am relatively new to iOS development and I come from a UIUX design background. I would like to know if there's a more efficient way or best practice in defining text styles the way Sketch or any other mainstream design tools do.

Example scenario, I have lots of screens with UIlabels and I would like to have a common text style for all header text. And then if I want to modify the text style I only modify it in one place and then the changes will be reflected on all UILabels that used that same text style just like in Sketch.

One solution I thought of is to create a subclass for UIlabel. But I am not sure if this is good practice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Creating a subclass for a UILabel is good idea. You can than easily change the class of specific label to set default (the one you set) look. I did the same with buttons in my project (in custom button class I only wrote required public init where I set all styles)

Comment: You can change ALL your label with `let labelAppearance = UILabel.appearance(); labelAppearance.font = <your_font>; labelAppearance.textColor = <yourColor>`

Comment: @QuocNguyen I've read about this method. But it's still a less ideal solution as if I want to define different styles to different UILabels, I would still have to resort to subclassing. So in that case, I might as well opt for subclassing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48812513/7715250 see my answer there, you could extend it alot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also use the power of `@IBInspectable`.

In your subclass, add an attribute like this :

```
@IBInspectable open var style : String = "" {
    didSet {
        switch style {
        case "head":
            font = //any font for head component
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your Xib/Storyboard ( or even in code ), you can set your attribute value in the property inspector

Answer (score 3):

set the global theme by using of `appearance` concept, for e.g

```
 UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = .white
```

or direct apply you can use like

```
  UILabel.appearance().textColor = .red
```

for e.g you get the sample [link](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/08/16/uiappearance-container-hierarchies/) or else use **extension** for your label.

Comment: This is an ideal solution if all UILabels or UIButtons would have the same styles. But if I have multiple styles I wanted to use for different buttons, I would still have to use subclassing which will then be a bit tedious. I think the best solution would be to use a subclass in combination with CZ54's suggestion to add @IBInspectable.

Comment: @CrisDenopol - then use subclass or IBInspectable or extension

Answer (score 0):

I do this differently. Just create a TextConstants.swift where you put all of your text related constants and then refer to the specific constant in your code.

Example:

The below code resides in the TextConstants.swift file.

```
struct FontsAndSizes {
    static let System_20_Regular = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .regular)
}

struct AttributedText {
    static let ModuleViewHeader = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28, weight: .bold),
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: Colors.GreyTextDark] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
}
```

Then you refer to the above constants in your code.

Example:

```
sectionLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: module.name, attributes: AttributedText.ModuleViewHeader)
```

or

```
sectionLabel.font = FontsAndSizes.System_20_Regular
```

I find it this method quite handy because

1. It is easy to modify.
2. It is easy to add new stuff.

Also, you won't see much `underscore_case` naming in Swift. But I find them useful in this specific case because they are better distinguished when you have many different fonts and styles.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass or use `@IBInspectable` is the easiest ways. 
Another one is use definition of these controls from a `json` file located locally or downloaded from your backend. This way, you can easier configure and change the style by modifying `json` file.